# PHP how to remove all other operators except -

Tags: php

i want to remove all other operators except -. i worked on the following but stuck here.

```
$s1 = "Hello@*&^%$#@!)({}[]?.,<> dis$ is. testing -";
$s2 = "- i love% the way. it, works";

for($ii=0;$ii<3;$ii++){

$from = array('/\(|\)/','/\d+ml|\d+g/','/\s+/'); 
$to = array('','','-'); 

$sample=${'s' . $ii}; 

$sample = strtolower(trim(preg_replace($from,$to,$sample),'-')); 
echo $sample."<br>";

}
```

please help me in this regards.

**Output required**

```
hello-dis-is-testing
i-love-the-way-it-works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sample = trim(preg_replace('/\\W+/i', '-', $s1), '-');
```

This regex replaces everything except letters and numbers with a dash and trim removes trailing and preceding dashes

Comment: Don't forget to make it case insensitive.